# APL Idiom to surround an array with zeros

Tags: apl, dyalog

Is there a simple idiom in (Dyalog) APL to surround a numeric array with zeros?

Currently for a numerical array `NA` of rank 1, or a vector I use

```
0,⍨0, NA
```

and for an array of rank 2 I use

```
0,[1]⍨0,[1]0,⍨0, NA
```

For higher ranks I could just repeat the pattern, but I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this (and with one definition for all ranks), but I just can't come up with one that doesn't seem overly complicated.

Comment: is `NA` numeric?

Comment: It was for the use case I had in mind, but something which is more generic is probably more useful

Comment: if you don't state that explicitly in the question, I'll have to delete my answer - it's under fire for not supporting the general case

Comment: thanks­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Is `NA` simple? (If the first element is nested, @ngn's answer is won't work.)

Comment: In the case I had at the time it was simple, but an idiom that works on things that may not be simple is potentially of more use to me (and probably others) in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Dyalog APL version 16.0 solution (from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104069/43319)) handles any number of dimensions:

```
{⍵@(1+⍳⍴⍵)⊢0⍴⍨2+⍴⍵}
```

`⍵` the array

`@(` placed at

`1+` one plus

`⍳` all the indices of

`⍴⍵` the shape of the array

`)⊢` in the array consisting of

`0⍴⍨` zero reshaped to the shape

`2+` two added to

`⍴⍵` the shape of the array

In other words, we create an array entirely of 0s, which in every dimension is two elements larger than the array, then we place the array into that array (thus replacing the 0s in those positions) at an offset of one from the edges, i.e. in the center.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P7i0qCi/NC/lUduE6ke9Wx00DLUf9W5@1LsFyNF81LXIAMxcYaQNEapF6FBQMFIwVjABi282MgEA)

[Alternative version](https://tio.run/##hZRBb9MwFMfv@xTv1lR0W9uNS7SJVQghJDRVygVp4uAlThuW2pWdbK2gHDiUtSJoAyG4cNgK0g7c1gq0I3wTf5HxbKfdpmVQWY3jxL/3f@//YtKNl4M@iXnrkiRqePRSZRd4UeNT@NdPZV@hKWgY9ZZDEVEWxH3YWlnSj6quq95/8p483m48BZw92i7eLqMWIzEQ1gcqBBeQcPBJHFNhMH57T8upqvHkGi6bqeFHlDi4hcPF5RyZsphKqV82pDhkIEKGtLVNRG0/hDrUVTYt6VT1mOEoXWfxLhWEBRKIoBCmzE8izuQDQ6trZZqpDs9yngaV3CJFmF0ANgzmxkoJ7PKkDbsUyYL0pSG@Rpiba8FkD9/iAKsKbcD/wvJ1eBCFERUQSQtzdaAtUMMPYElbhu5pN3PYpAh20xQaUz9BMwyyAh0i9wBvIxbQnuFhJTdqG6/U6MRzG4hs7HjPTYiLPFGnYSOW8UFOZVQmNHBBUOK3V/0255JaZMRahtoNe/PmG504aA7Oymp4jJxBsVKdNnRNC1pj1o0xwhhTU6PvBjL13MLNOjZ0UploL/ZtyjgkNiCx/Xd/gRt9Q3WryPp95mlf3FtW6CLJNunSBdIKAx7qDfaZoT4ztfmlsokmj08r3t1esLRDReTnYq0z2Ie5XINrIq6yo7Lz2r08XfTiuKLGb@5qm67gL3KOz1nIRYfsxhQOImzLRQjDxjukO8h6Vlbvfjb/1zSLfbmTP4yiiVPb/PN51cxnZdvPg6LDgLVQhm5e6wGE2g67SnsJZXLOZ/QAA8geXLWcVlBcQnoA@yROqbS8G0IRiyCNO/yygp3s2L6b4krZnDJTfL@Ml@oVcCFFW3uNrs8uW06Ddub5ZtOmJc@riOQjhNxSSjp4iNLAfncrS4NLL8VDMWWBLeaMJI72@PyqkFUzPatb52eDy8UWfUitwbpZP6@v/wU) that defines an `at` operator and can therefore be used pre-16.0.

Comment: @Probie Yes. I'll post an alternative solution that works in older versions too.

Comment: @Probie I've added a link that allows you to "poly-fill" `@`.

Answer (score 2):

[`(¯2-⍴)↑(1+⍴)↑⊢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNQ@uNdB/1btF81DZRw1AbynrUtQgorWCkYKxgAhR61LvZyAQA)­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: It may well be that OP uses `0` as an example padding. Furthermore, OP does not specify what `NA` contains. Your solution only works on numeric arrays where the first element is a simple scalar number. It fails, e.g. [on character arrays](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNQ@uNdB/1btF81DZRw1AbynrUtQgorWCkYKxgAhR61DfVEQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") and [nested arrays](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNQ@uNdB/1btF81DZRw1AbynrUtQgorfCod7ORgrGCCQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online"). And it cannot be customised to surround with anything but the prototypical element.

Comment: @Adám Surely 0 means 0 :) "NA" is suggestive of "numeric array". Yes, it's possible, though not very likely, that Probie meant something else.

Comment: **N**-dimensional **A**rray ;-)

Comment: As Adám has said, there's no need to make such assumptions. ;-) Also, while Probie most probably knows APL well enough, you may want to add an explanation of the code in case an APL beginner happens to read it (and to avoid automatic VLQ flags).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The OP has amended the question. I'd prefer to keep my answer concise, but feel free to edit your own explanation in if you think that helps, or flag it as VLQ you really consider my answer "very low quality"

Answer (score 1):

```
{r←≢⍴⍵ ⋄ i←1⌽⍳r ⋄ {0⍪0⍪⍨i⍉⍵}⍣r⊢⍵}
```

`⍴⍵` the shape of the array
`≢` the number of elements of that (i.e. array's rank)
`r←` store that as `r` (for **r**ank)

`⍳r` the **ɩ**ndices of the rank
`1⌽` rotate them one step
`i←` store in `i` (for **i**ndices)

`⊢⍵` on the array
`{`…`}⍣r` apply the following function `r` times (i.e. once per dimension):
 `i⍉⍵` reorder the axes of the argument according to `i` (i.e. put the next dimension in front)
 `0⍪⍨` append with 0s along the first axis
 `0⍪` prepend with 0s along the first axis

In other words, each axis gets its turn at being in front, where we prepend and append 0s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P7i0qCi/NC/lUduE6iIg8ahz0aPeLY96tyo86m5RyASKGD7q2fuod3MRWKDa4FHvKhB@1Lsi81FvJ1Bh7aPexUWPuhaBmAjzFBSMFIwVTMBmbTYyAQA)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your own answer; you can reduce instead of recursing:

```
{⊃{0,[⍺]⍵,[⍺]0}/(⍳≢⍴⍵),⊂⍵}
```

`⊂⍵` enclose the array
`(`…`),` prepend the following:
 `⍴⍵` the shape of the array
 `≢` the number of elements of that (i.e. array's rank)
 `⍳r` the **ɩ**ndices of the rank
`{`…`}/` reduce (insert between the elements) using the following function:
 `⍵,[⍺]0` append 0s along the axis indicated by the left argument
 `0,[⍺]⍵` prepend 0s along the axis indicated by the left argument
`⊃` disclose (because the reduction reduces the rank from 1 to 0, so it has to enclose the result)

In other words, we prepend and append 0s along all each axis in turn.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P7i0qCi/NC/lUduE6kddzdUGOtGPenfFPurdCmEY1OprPOrd/Khz0aPeLUBRTZ1HXU1AuhahVUHBSMFYwQQsv9nIBAA)

Comment: That's pretty cool, and was probably the answer I was looking for (although I'll probably accept either your `@` solution or ngn's use of the fill behaviour of `↑` since if someone searches for this question it seems like those are better solutions). I'm pretty new to APL, Are there any good exercises for thinking more like an APL programmer? My statically typed background means I'd never have thought of using reduce over an array with the last element as a different type.

Comment: @Probie Just notice my comment to ngn's solution. Freeing ones mind of other programming languages' influence happens gradually  as you use APL. You may be interested in [the APL chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405), and the [lessons there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405?tab=conversations), especially [Lesson 27](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/conversation/lesson-27-lookup-without-replacement).

Answer (score 0):

So, I've generalised my method to a recursive dfn which meets my "works for arbitrary rank" requirement, but I'm not happy with it because I still think there's a better way to do it that I'm just missing. I've put it as an answer, since it technically answers my question, but I'm still looking for better solutions.

```
{(⍴⍴⍵){⍺=0:⍵ ⋄ (⍺-1)∇0,[⍺]⍨0,[⍺]⍵}⍵}
```